# Internal representation of a number in R

Tags: r, precision

```
> trunc(26015)
[1] 26015
> 260.15*100
[1] 26015
> trunc(260.15*100)
[1] 26014
> floor(260.15*100)
[1] 26014
> as.integer(260.15*100)
[1] 26014
```

For this code in R, is there an issue with the internal representation of the number?
When I do 260.15*100, the number being printed is still 26015, but when I use a function like trunc() or as.integer(), it becomes 26014.
Usually, my value containing the decimal comes from another variable. So how do I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The print method for a numeric is not the same as its internal representation. `260.15 * 100` is never actually 26015, it is just printed as such. `print.numeric` uses rounding. The underlying `numeric` data is floating point. You can see this by changing your print options:

```
# set print.numeric() to display up to 22 digits, the maximum possible
> options(digits = 22)
> 260.15 * 100
[1] 26014.99999999999636202
> 26015
[1] 26015
```

In lieu of `trunc()` or `as.integer()`, does `round()` meet your needs?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, round() does give me the right value. But is there no way to store 260.15*100 as 26015 itself? Also, is this inconsistently stored? Because trunc(160.15*100) gives 16015 itself. And using round() is not an option for me as I actually want truncation to get the whole number. In some cases, I do have decimal values, so I can't round them off, but need to just truncate them.

Comment: 260.15 * 100 is < 26015 in floating point arithmetic. There's no inconsistency in `trunc()` - some numbers come in a little higher or lower. That's fp math. `trunc()` is an approximate decimal operation implemented against inexact fp numbers. R has no binary coded or exact decimal data type - non integer non fp decimal math is rare in modern languages. If you need to preserve decimals at a specific fixed point (i.e. cents for accountancy) you can use integers and divide by 100 as a final step. Otherwise the best approach depends on your specific need. `round()` lets you specify decimal places.